# html dropdownlist helper in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor, html-helper

I'd to set a local javascript variable to the output of an html helper. See the following snippet for an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
              var dtypes = '@Html.DropDownList("TypeId",new SelectList(@ViewBag.MyTypes,"Value","Text"))';
      });
      alert(dtypes);
</script>
```

This doesn't give me an alert. Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks for any help.

Comment: This code doesn't make any sense.  `@Html.DropDownList` produces HTML markup for a `<select>` element.  What exactly are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'd like to use the html markup in my js.

Comment: I bet you're getting a syntax error when using this.  The `DropDownList` method will put in some new lines into its output so your string is unterminated.  You will likely have to create your own extension method to make this work.  Or, better yet, why have the HTML markup in a Javascript object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should encode your html to be valid JavaScript string:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(function () {
          var dtypes = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList("TypeId",new SelectList(@ViewBag.MyTypes,"Value","Text")))';
  });
  alert(dtypes);
</script>
```

Comment: I'm having a similar problem with a @HTML helper DropDownList.  I copied and pasted your code into my .cshtml file and I get an "overload ... has some invalid arguments" error on the Ajax.JavaScriptsStringEncode method. Any ideas why it wouldn't work in a C# Razor file?

Comment: If I enclose the string in "" and then escaped the "s within the string with \" the encode worked: var dtypes = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode("Html.DropDownList(\"TypeId\",new SelectList(@ViewBag.MyTypes,\"Value\",\"Text\"))")'; It didn't solve my problem though since I'm encoding to inject into a node with jQuery .html().  But when injected into a node it renders as a string not a HTML DropDownList Helper. Please see my post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904426/update-html-with-html-helper-dropdownlist

Comment: You should surround Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode with Html.Raw so you need `@Html.Raw(Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode())`

Comment: var dtypes = @Html.Raw(Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList("TypeId",new SelectList(@ViewBag.MyTypes,"Value","Text")))); gives the same "invalid argument" error.  Would you please write out fully your suggested syntax for your original var dtypes example. Even if that encoding would work will it render as html code, not as a text string, when updating a node with .html()?  Best to answer at my http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904426/update-html-with-html-helper-dropdownlist post since we are getting quite a bit afar of the original question in this post.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode("")` and `\` in the string  before quotation mark.

Your code would be:

```
var dtypes = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode("Html.DropDownList(\"TypeId\", 
   new SelectList(@ViewBag.MyTypes,\"Value\",\"Text\"))")';
```

Answer (score 0):

Encode your html helper with @Ajax.JavascriptStringEncode(); And dont forget to convert the Html.DropDownList Helper to string with .ToString().

Here is an example:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
      var dtypes = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList("TypeId",new SelectList(@ViewBag.MyTypes,"Value","Text")).ToString())';
     });
    alert(dtypes);
</script>
```