# update .html with @HTML helper DropDownList

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

MVC4, C#, jQuery, Razor view (.cshtml)

I'm trying to update the .html() of a node with a @HTML.DropDownList:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#CmpMASttF').html('@Html.DropDownList("CmpAdrsSt.State", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._State) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CmpAdrsSt.State) '); 
</script>
```

This works fine for a @HTML.EditorFor:

```
$('#CmpMASttF').html('@Html.EditorFor(m => m.CmpAdrsSt.State) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CmpAdrsSt.State) ');
```

This is the node being updated:

```
        <tr class="CmpMA"><td tate: </td>
        <td  colspan="4" ><span id="CmpMASttF" class="editor-field"></span> </td></tr>
```

The @HTML.DropDownList code works fine by itself so that is not the source of the problem:

```
        <tr><td>State: </td>
        <td  colspan="4"><span class="editor-field">
              @Html.DropDownList("CmpAdrsSt.State", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._State)
              @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CmpAdrsSt.State)</span> </td></tr>
```

When I try and update the node with the @HTML.DropDownList with the jQuery .html() all the code in the javascript block is disabled.

I tried encoding the string:

```
var test = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode("Html.DropDownList(\"CmpAdrsSt.State\",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._State)")'
```

but when injected into the .html() it renders as a string not a HTML DropDownList helper (adding the @ before HTML, "@HTML.DropDownList ..., makes no difference).

How do you update the .html() of a node with a @HTML.DropDownList?

Thank you

Comment: +1 for demonstrating that Razor can be injected into Javascript literals. Shame it only works in the simpler cases.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting use of Html helper injection... The Html.DropDownList generates multiple lines though, generating an unterminated javascript string. How do you plan to get around that?

### Why not inject it into a dummy script template div instead and have your JQuery simply copy it?

```
<script id="template" type="text/template">
    @Html.DropDownList("CmpAdrsSt.State", (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._State) @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.CmpAdrsSt.State) 
</script>
```

Then copy using:

```
$('#CmpMASttF').html($('#template').html());
```

I prefer this to trying to inject HTML into Javascript string literals, as this gives better separation of the UI from the code.

Comment: Thanks HiTech.  I wished I had checked the post again 3 hours ago.  I just spent the whole morning coming up with another work around.  I plugged in your code and it works and is simpler than the work around I was just about to post as the answer.