# @Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode not working in Razor View

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, html-helper

MVC4 C#

When I place this code in a Razor view (.cshtml) I get a "overload ... invalid arguments" error.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var test = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode(Html.DropDownList("CmpAdrsSt.State",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._State))';
</script>
```

How do I get the Ajax encoder to work in a Razor view?  OR is there a better way to encode the @HTML.DropDownList helper?  (I need to encode it for injection into a node with jQuery .html() )

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I enclosed the string in "" and then escaped the "s within the string with \" the encode worked:

```
var test = '@Ajax.JavaScriptStringEncode("Html.DropDownList(\"CmpAdrsSt.State\",(IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag._State)")'
```

but when injected into the node with jQuery .html() it renders as a string not a HTML DropDownList. helper.  That is a secondary question though, see my post [update .html with @HTML helper DropDownList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17904426/update-html-with-html-helper-dropdownlist)